# What frameworks for depth cameras are out there?

Tags: kinect, openni

I want to evaluate the performance of several SDKs / frameworks for depth cameras. These cameras can either be using Time-of-Flight or structured light.
The framework should be capable (at least) of person tracking / blob detection and gesture recognition.
So far I found the following frameworks:

- [OpenNI](http://openni.org/) (structured light only)
- [Microsoft Kinect SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/overview.aspx) (Kinect only)
- [Beckon SDK](http://www.omekinteractive.com/) by Omek Interactive (ToF and structured light)
- [iisu](http://www.iisu.com/) by SoftKinetic (ToF and structured light)

Are there any other frameworks I should be aware of?

EDIT: I found [this article](http://www.techradar.com/news/world-of-tech/beyond-kinect-5-next-gen-gesture-systems-1062885) by Techradar that seems to indicate that these are indeed the only options currently available.

Any feedback would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Note that the Microsoft Kinect SDK does not support gesture recognition on its own. You will need a 3rd party library such as GesturePak (http://www.franklins.net/gesturepak.aspx). Similar to that, OpenNI is usually used in conjunction with NITE for gesture recognition.

Comment: There is also the Voxel SDK by Texas Instruments (https://github.com/3dtof/voxelsdk).

Answer (score 2):

I have found some interesting links on this. You can take MIT's approach using [CodAC](http://www.rle.mit.edu/stir/codac/) . They list lots of facts on this post, the most important ones I will post here.

```
9. What are limitations of this technique?

The main limitation of our framework is inapplicability to scenes with curvilinear
objects, which would require extensions of the current mathematical model.
Another limitation is that a periodic light source creates a wrap-around error 
as it does in other TOF devices. For scenes in which surfaces have high reflectance
or texture variations, availability of a traditional 2D image prior to our data   
acquisition allows for improved depth map reconstruction as discussed in our paper.

10. What are advantages of this technique/device and how does it 
compare with existing TOF-based range sensing techniques?

In laser scanning, spatial resolution is limited by the scanning time. 
TOF cameras do not provide high spatial resolution because they rely on a 
low-resolution 2D pixel array of range-sensing pixels. CoDAC is a single-sensor,
high spatial resolution depth camera which works by exploiting the sparsity of natural 
scene structure.

11. What is the range resolution and spatial resolution of the CoDAC system?

We have demonstrated sub-centimeter range resolution in our experiments.
This is significantly better than fundamental limit of about 10 cm that would 
arise from using a detector with 0.7 nanosecond rise time if we were not using 
parametric signal modeling.  The improvement in range resolution comes from the 
parametric modeling and deconvolution in our framework. We refer the reader to 
our publications for complete details and analysis.

We have demonstrated 64-by-64 pixel spatial resolution,
as this is the spatial resolution of our spatial light modulator.  
Spatially patterning with a digital micromirror device (DMD) will enable 
much higher spatial resolution.  Our experiments use only 205 projection patterns,
which correspond to just 5% of number of pixels in the reconstructed depth map. 
This is a significant improvement over raster scanning in LIDAR, and it is 
obtained without the 2D sensor array used in TOF cameras.
```

Also another interesting project I found on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeDtWWuxSXA) uses [`libfreenect`](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) and [`libusb`](http://www.libusb.org/)

There is also [`dSensingNI`](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2148179&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=102784528&CFTOKEN=17576651) which is described as

```
This work presents an approach to overcome the disadvantages of existing interaction 
frameworks and technologies for touch detection and object interaction. The robust and
easy to use framework dSensingNI (Depth Sensing Natural Interaction) is described, 
which supports multitouch and tangible interaction with arbitrary objects. It uses 
images from a depth-sensing camera and provides tracking of users fingers of palm of
hands and combines this with object interaction, such as grasping, grouping and 
stacking, which can be used for advanced interaction techniques.
```

So you have hit most of them out there, especially that use Kinect, but there are a few other options out there! Hope this Helps!